# Check domain or IP that request came from?

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet, is it possible to check if a request came from a specific domain, say "example.com"?

```
public abstract class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws ServletException, IOException 
{
        if (didOriginateFrom("example.com", req)) {
            // ok to process
        }
    }
}
```

I have one server that will offload some work to a secondary server (above), just want to make sure it only process requests that come from my primary server,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below methods give you the information of the client host machine which has made the request.

- `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()`
- `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteHost()`

Here is the code you are looking for:

```
boolean didOriginateFrom(Sting host, HttpServletRequest req) {
   return req.getRemoteHost().contains(host);
}
```

Both the above methods gives information about the client or the last proxy address that sent the request.

Some servers might return the original client address though the request has come through several proxies. Proxies send the address of the immediate client to the server by adding [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header. Thus some servers might process the [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header values and return the original client address.

Here is how the [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) request header might look

```
X-Forwarded-For : originalclient, proxy1, proxy2, lastproxy
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , `javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServerName()` should work. It also provides further methods to retrieve request information, getScheme(), getServerPort()...

Comment: The Question was about knowing the address of the client making the request not the server address.